# How to loop to this array

Tags: php, arrays

i have this array as output.

```
array(2) { ["Datum"]=> string(10) "2017-05-29" ["ID"]=> array(2) { [2]=> string(19) "75528705-1431953348" [3]=> string(21) "1081357825-1445504448" } }
```

how can i loop through this array in php ?

this is the code to read the array

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
$val = $_POST;
?>
```

I have already try this

```
<?php
foreach($_POST->ID as $val) {
print "waarde = " . $val . " <BR>";
}
?>
```

Comment: `$_POST['ID']` instead of `$_POST->ID`

Comment: thade made it , thank you

Comment: `->` is for accessing object properties. Why would you use that for an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a declaration of your provided `$_POST` array:

```
$_POST=array(
    "Datum" => "2017-05-29",
    "ID" => array(
        2 => "75528705-1431953348",
        3 => "1081357825-1445504448"
    )
);
```

You can directly access any of its elements by referencing its keys:

```
echo $_POST["Datum"];  // prints 2017-05-29
print_r($_POST["ID"]); // prints Array([2] => 75528705-1431953348 [3] => 1081357825-1445504448 )
echo $_POST["ID"][2];  // prints 75528705-1431953348
echo $_POST["ID"][3];  // prints 1081357825-1445504448
```

You are not dealing with an [object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php), so the -> will not work.

Using a foreach loop on the `$_POST["ID"]` subarray will let you access all of the elements in the subarray.

Code:

```
foreach($_POST["ID"] as $val){
    echo "waarde = $val<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
waarde = 75528705-1431953348
waarde = 1081357825-1445504448
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   foreach($_POST['ID'] as $index => $str) {
       echo "waarde = " . $str . "<br/>";
   }
?>
```